# Is reputation the same between meta and main?

Tags: support, reputation

Although I have no reputation activity on meta (my reputation tab says "There aren't yet any reputation changes to show"), I still see the same reputation score here as I do on security.stackexchange.com. Is this by design for this site, all beta sites, or a bug?

[image: Comparison of meta and main header bars showing the same reputation score]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's how all meta sites work except meta.stackoverflow.com, which was historically the entire network's meta site.

Comment: I need to spend more time on meta.*